# Custom controls library for ios SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk, interface-builder

I don't want to rewrite the wheel and I am looking for custom controls to reuse in xcode to enhance the interface of my iphone app. This set of custom controls sounded promising but unfortunately it redirects to a 404 page :

https://github.com/eisernWolf/TouchCustoms

Do you have any suggestion of such good library for custom buttons, textareas, list, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a couple of popular open-source libraries.

[TapKu](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)

[Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20)

Comment: looks promising, in particular three20, thanks ! I'm wondering how I never encountered those with all the websites I have been browsing for iOS coding...

Answer (score 6):

This is a great site for custom iOS controls.  http://www.cocoacontrols.com

Answer (score 3):

That URL probably linked to a fork of TouchCustoms, the original github page is here: https://github.com/nesterow/TouchCustoms.